# why is no data being returned in my PowerShell script

Tags: oracle, powershell

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient
$username = "SYSTEM"
$password = "password"
$data_source = "production"
$connection_string = "User Id=$username;Password=$password;Data Source=$data_source"

try{
$statement = "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL"
$con = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connection_string)

$con.Open()

$cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $statement

$result = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
# Do something with the results...
Write-Host $result + "data"
If($result.HasRows) {
    try {
    while ($result.Read())
        {
            "[0] : " + $result.GetValue(0)
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        #log error
    }
    finally
    {
        $con.Close() 
    }
}

} catch {
    Write-Error (“Database Exception: {0}`n{1}” -f `
        $con.ConnectionString, $_.Exception.ToString())
} finally{
    if ($con.State -eq ‘Open’) { $con.close() }
}
```

I am executing SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL

I am expecting 21-MAY-19

However no data is returned. (no error is presented either)

Comment: You are assigning values to variables, that doesn't generate any output. I see only one `Write-Error` in the catch.

Comment: I tried it too and it works. sounds like you want to have powershell show the values of $result (there is no command here to do that).

Comment: What they are trying to say is that you are storing the output in `$result` but not printing it out. Just put a `$result` at the end of your script.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above comments, you've to send the content of `$result` to PowerShells output stream. The output stream is used to realize the pipeline feature of Powershell. If you wrap your code in e.g. "myCode.ps1" and invoke it via:

```
.\myCode.ps1
```

The content of `$result` is pushed in the output stream (pipeline). Since no other cmdlet is attached to the call of `myCode.ps1` the Powershell host (= your command line)  will receive the content. The default behavior of the host is to dump the content.

So add the following to your code:

```
$result = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
# Return $result to the pipeline
$result
```

Read more about pipelines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6) and more about streams [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/).

**UPDATE1:** This [link](https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2016/03/querying-an-oracle-database-from-powershell/) describes more or less the code sample of the question. Maybe the Orcale .NET data provider is missing. Add it via:

```
 Add-Type -Path "PathToDll\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I added that and I am getting no results. SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL is supposed to always return a value.

Comment: @softwareisfun, maybe you need to add the oracle data provider, as described [here](https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2016/03/querying-an-oracle-database-from-powershell/)

Comment: @softwareisfun did you try if the data provider was missing?

Comment: @Moerwald did you know, how to catch exception if sql return no rows selected? I know that with pl/sql block code could use:
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
--do something here
END;

But I have no idea how to use pl/sql inside powershell script.